# Sort a hash by value in descending order and then key in ascending order ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash like this

```
 trial_hash ={"key1"=>1000, "key2"=>34, "key3"=>500, "key4"=>500, "key5"=>500, "key6"=>500}
```

I order it in descending order of the value:

```
 my_hash = trial_hash.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse
```

I get it this way now:

```
 [["key1", 1000], ["key4", 500], ["key5", 500], ["key6", 500], ["key3", 500], ["key2", 34]]
```

But I want it to be sorted in ascending order of key when the value is same. How do I do it?

For eg: The above hash would be ordered this way:

```
 [["key1", 1000], ["key3", 500], ["key4", 500], ["key5", 500], ["key6", 500], ["key2", 34]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a comparison, arrays get evaluated first by their first elements, then by their second, etc. You can use this fact to enumerate sequential comparisons. Comparing by `[-v, k]` first sorts by value (in reverse order) then by key.

```
>> trial_hash.sort_by{|k, v| [-v, k]}
=> [["key1", 1000], ["key3", 500], ["key4", 500], ["key5", 500], ["key6", 500], ["key2", 34]]
```

Comment: cool.. thanks! I had tried this trial_hash.sort_by{|k, v| [v,-Integer(k)]}.reverse but then key was not string so it didn't work, I made the key 1 instead of key1 it worked. but your new code is awesome.